# Enable Comments at Checkout

Tags: orders, onepage-checkout, messages

Does Magento have the option without an extension to enable customers to leave order notes?  I am aware of gift messages functionality.  But have never located simple note functionality.

This is so the customer can leave order notes like "please call before processing" or "please do not include prices on invoice in box".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the stub code is in there for Community Edition to enable the comments section, but the actual implementation was saved for EE.

There once was a thread over on the Magento Commerce forums telling you how to create the module to connect with the stub code and enable the comments, but basically, YES, you need a module and a template update in order to add the necessary code for the comment box to be visible, fillable, saveable and retrievable.

Comment: Thanks.  So dumb they consider this an enterprise feature.  It's comments...

Comment: Yes, pretty ridiculous, all that's needed is an observer, a text area in the cart and if you want it in email, a template macro. This is based on Ben George's original MagEBay'd Magento forum post => http://www.joomlavision.com/add-order-comments-magento-checkout/

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't just use translations for gift message if it's not needed too.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

ladle3000,magento did not have  any feature for showing this type of feature.
You can use magento default feature  Agreement by this you can do this.

But suggest you please use any third party extension

Comment: Are you speaking of terms and conditions?  I think that feature is intimidating to the customer.